# Смена номера таблицы базы данных раз в сутки

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.

Имеется база данных test, в ней 31 таблица для каждого дня месяца.
В php файле записываются данные с датчиков в определенную таблицу. Возможно ли записывать данные в таблицу с порядковым номером текущего дня?
Например 5го числа записывать в таблицу с именем sensor5, 6-го числа в sensor6 и т.д.

Вот текущий код:

```
<?php
$dbusername = "name";
$dbpassword = "password";
$server = "ipserver"; 
$dbconnect = mysql_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$dbselect = mysql_select_db("test",$dbconnect);
$sql = "INSERT INTO sensor1(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7) VALUES ('".$_GET["value1"]."','".$_GET["value2"]."','".$_GET["value3"]."','".$_GET["value4"]."','".$_GET["value5"]."','".$_GET["value6"]."','".$_GET["value7"]."')";      
mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: можно, но подход неверный. иметь на каждый день по таблице - плодить 365 таблиц на год - неразумно. Надо сделать одну таблицу с нужными колонками или несколько, которые будут связаны по какому-то признаку (см. нормализация БД)

Comment: Ну и не стоит использовать расширение `mysql` оно уже лет 5 как не развивается, а в 7 версии PHP вообще удалено. Используйте `mysqli` или `PDO`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Т.е. например создать одну таблицу для одного месяца. Добавить колонку "День" и добавлять номер дня для каждой строки данных. И потом использовать уже данные по нужному номеру в колонке?

Comment: @D.Sakulin не "день", а "Дата". в которой вполне себе можно хранить полную дату с точностью до секунды. и остальные колонки value1,value2 и т.д. где будут данные.... то есть записываются дата и данные одновременно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Кажется дошло. У меня сейчас уже таймстемп записывается вместе с данными отдельной колонкой. Тогда я могу взять эту дату и если день совпадает с текущим, то я ее использую, верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Алексей Шиманский уже написал:

   > но подход неверный. иметь на каждый день по таблице - плодить 365 таблиц на год - неразумно. Надо сделать одну таблицу с нужными колонками или несколько, которые будут связаны по какому-то признаку

Заводите одно таблицу со всеми данными, какие нужны и добавляете столбец:

```
ALTER TABLE `sensor` ADD COLUMN `date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

в него будет автоматом записываться дата вставки записи (если Вы не укажете значение этого поля).
Также добавляете индекс по этому полю:

```
ALTER TABLE `sensor` ADD INDEX (`date`);
```

Далее, когда нужно узнать за какой-то день данные делаете запрос:

```
SELECT `value2`,`value4` FROM `sensor` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m-%d') = ?;
```

2. Если всё же нужно именно записывать в каждую отдельную таблицу, то можно это сделать вот так:

   ```
   $today = date('j');
   $sql = "INSERT INTO sensor$today(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7)
   VALUES ('".$_GET["value1"]."','".$_GET["value2"]."','".$_GET["value3"]."','".$_GET["value4"]."','".$_GET["value5"]."','".$_GET["value6"]."','".$_GET["value7"]."')";
   ```
3. Вот так будет выглядеть коннект для PDO в Вашем случае:

   ```
   $dbconnect = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=test;charset=cp1251", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
   ```

   Подробнее здесь:

[ссылка1](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

[ссылка2](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)